# Android DashClock Extension setup for CM Home (CyanogenMod 11)

Tags: java, android, cyanogenmod, dashclock

today I coded a DashClock Extension in Java for DashClock Widget by Roman Nurik (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&hl=de). 
Everthing works fine but the extension doesn't show up in CM Home. I have googled much time and don't have found any Solution.

What I must do to support CM Home?

Edit: I'm using DashClock Widget v1.6 and API v2. The change of "protocolVersion" from 1 to 2 make no difference.

Comment: Do you mean Trebuchet when you say CM Home?  Like the default Launcher?  You shouldn't have to do anything.  Add dashclock widget, click settings, and add it as extension?

Comment: Yes I mean in the Trebuchet launcher. I have added my extension by Widget. The Extension shows up in the Lockscreen, but not in the CM Home (Trebuchet)

Comment: huh so your extension shows on lock screen but not on home screen?  strange!  Maybe remove and readd widget, I'm not sure if dashclock caches extensions?

Comment: On my old Galaxy S3 only one Extension wasn't show, on my new OnePlus One not any extension is working, both phones have the newest nightlys installed. I think this is just a bug in CM11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If I use DashClock API v1.1 everything works fine! No idea what the CM Home problem is with API v2.

Comment: The only thing I changed was the library import from v2 to v1.1